# base64 to Blob removing the metadata available with the image

Tags: image, base64, blob

I am using below method to convert base64 to blob:

```
var blobData = new Blob([base64Str], {type: 'image/png'});
```

Now once the image file is created using this Blob:

```
var imageData = new FormData();
var counter = 1;
imageData.append("file", blobData, 'file1.png');
```

I do not see the metadata. Is there a way to add the metadata being stripped off the image file?

I download the image file created above and view it in http://metapicz.com/#landing

When viewing original image it shows the location info and other metadata, but when viewing the downloaded image it does not show any metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself, the datatype returned from iOS native (swift) is UIImage which removed the EXIF information and only returns base64 of image data.

Changed the code to return entire image data + metadata at iOS native side.